# Как связать таблицы в базе данных (PHP, MySQLi)

Tags: база-данных, php, связывание-данных, структуры, mysql

Делаю  БД для менеджера, на сайте нужно (создавать и удалять категории/товары). Никак не могу придумать как связать на MySQLi эти таблицы. Вот пример:

[image]

или пример №2:

[image]

В каждой ветке. глубина не ограничена. Например, в ветке быт товары будет 2 под таблиц а в ветке моб телефоны -  4 под таблицы.

Так вот, сам вопрос: При выводе в PHP создается меню из главного списка, и дальше переход к след таблицам., то есть нужно как-то связать записи одной таблицы с другой. я думаю может в таблицах с Категориями, создавать отдельный столбец, и туда записывать ссылки на его дочерную таблицу? а таблицам генерировать какое-то уникальное имя

Comment: это всего две таблицы. категории и товары. создаете поле в обеих parentid - ссылка на родительскую категорию.

Comment: Если всего 2 таблицы, то допустим 1000 товаров, и поиск уже дольше, особенно с моб интернетом. А так таблицы объема не имеют, зато быстродействие растет. По этому не 2 таблицы а больше, много будет

Comment: Или же все-таки эффективней 2 таблицы? но а перебор данных, не замедлит работу существенно?

Comment: 1. у вас база вся будет в памяти в любом случае. 1000 товаров - это копейки. дойдете до размеров базы в 10 гигов, поговорим отдельно, что делать дальше.
2. выводить в корзине, а также осуществлять поиск по всему каталогу товаров из разных таблиц вам будет гораздо неудобнее и по времени тоже проиграете.
3. "перебирать всю таблицу" субд никогда не будет. нужен индекс по parentid и все.
4. когда владельцы магазина захотят создать новую категорию, им вас придется звать чтоб базу изменить?
5. про мобильный интернет не понял.

Comment: 4. Нет, категории добавлять зависимо от товара в продаже. Нужно что-бы категории добавлялись.Если в 2х таблицах можно с добавление категорий?
5.моб интернет, просто эту система управляет каталогом, а само приложение под Android, нужно на сайте редактировать/добавлять а на телефоне - оформлять.

Comment: @Юра Сучко, база данных работает на сервере, для нее нет разницы, хапросили ее с мобильника или стационарника.

Comment: Я имею в виду, загрузка данных по моб сети дольше + пробежка по записям с parentid. В сумме это уже более ощутимая задержка.

Comment: @Юра Сучко, дополнительная задержка будет миллисекунд двадцать, может. С учетом того, что основная необходимость в этих категорий - для меню, то все довольно легко кэшируется хоть целым деревом, хоть для каждой категории. Ну и роль "естественных" затыков БД зачастую преувеличена, часто пхп тормозит сильнее или БД не настроена (отключено кэширование, медленный диск, шаред хостинг, нет индексов, запрос на поиск вызывает преобразование типов).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Юра Сучко](/users/14645/%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE), то, как вы поставили себе задачу, говорит, что у вас только все начинается. Тогда вам стоит начать с того, чтобы составить список действий, которые будут выполняться приложениями (браузером или мобильным приложением, не важно). По данному списку вы увидите какие данные и в каком виде вам понадобятся. Например (с примерами запросов):

1. Поиск по каталогу. Вам понадобится весь список товаров и при этом желательно чтоб список не надо было собирать из разных мест.

   ```
   select p.id, p.name from products p where p.name like :search_str
   ```
2. Отображение категорий и товаров в определенной категории, желательно универсально относительно родительской категории.

   ```
   select p.id, p.name from products p where p.parentid = :current_cat
   select c.id, c.name from categories c where c.parentid = :current_cat
   ```
3. Отображение корзины, в которой могут быть товары из любой категории

   ```
   select p.id, p.name, c.qty from cart c join product p on c.productid = p.id
   ```
4. Добавление товаров в определенную категорию, или категории в категорию, желательно без изменения структуры бд.

   ```
   insert into category (parentid, name) values (:parent_cat, :cat_name)
   insert into product (parentid, name) values (:parent_cat, :product_name)
   ```

Данная структура будет удобной и для админки, где редактировать каталог, так и для пользователей (десктопных или мобильных), ибо данные, которые нужны будут пользователю, будут возвращаться в том объеме, который вы уменьшить не сможете при всем своем желании.

Мобильное приложение, не знаю какое у вас предполагается, может быть таким:

1. копия сайта, просто оптимизированная под моб. устройства. тут никаких структур бд никто не увидит.
2. нативное приложение, которое также общается с web-сервером (через какой-то REST) в постоянном онлайне. тут также можно обойтись без каких-либо структур, просто отображать пришедшие данные и уметь составлять правильные запросы в соответствии с действиями пользователя.
3. Полноценный клиент (нативнй или html5/phonegap какой-нибудь). С возможностью просмотра каталога, с кэшированием любых данных, пришедших с сервера, для работы в офлайне. Здесь структура уже понадобится, и она может быть точно такой же как на сайте (да-да, на мобильных устройствах также есть sql-движок, см. ЗЫ). Вопрос трафика здесь не стоит, т.к. каталог меняется не так часто, в любом случае можно предусмотреть частичное обновление каталога, а заказ слать придется все равно.

ЗЫ синтаксис запросов любезно предоставлен сайтом sqlite.org